# Modifying et al usage in Biblio

Tags: mendeley, csl

I am trying to change "et al" usage in Mendeley's CSL editor for my bibliography only but having trouble with the settings. I want my bibliography to display 3 authors et al if there is more than 5 authors but up to all 5 authors if less than 5. Thank you for any advice. I am  relatively new to using CSL editor.

I have set the "et al min" to 5 and "et al use first" to 3. Not sure if this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

`et-al-min` to 6 (more than 5) and `et-al-use-first` to 3 is correct for what you want, yes. Note that you can enter that information in various places: The best way to do so is under "Bibliogaphy" [image: Bibliography Section of the Visual Editor]

If that doesn't work, make sure that you don't have different settings somewhere set for the authors, which would override this.